# How to pass quoted args to Visual Basic's Process.Start()

Tags: vb.net, cmd, process

I need to unpin my own program from the Taskbar using Visual Basic.
Therefor I am using the tool "syspin.exe", the final working command is:

syspin.exe "C:\Program Files\OEM\BrowserChoice\OEMBrowserChoice.exe" 5387

But I can't execute this command within my Visual Basic application.
I guess it's a problem with these quotes, single quotes do not work with syspin.exe, the command has to be exactly as above.

In VB I'm trying to execute it as follows:

```
Process.Start(INSTALL_PATH + "\syspin.exe", " ""C:\Program Files\OEM\BrowserChoice\OEMBrowserChoice.exe"" 5387")
```

I've tried many variations of this (Moved the quotes, spaces, put the args to String.Format, put the args to different strings), but nothing worked.

I don't wanna read something like: Don't do that, it's up to the user...
I am making a program for my custom built PCs, where the user can choose it's favorite browser and automatically replace the BrowserChoice utility with the actual Browser as part of my service to him.

But I am open to other ways this might work using Visual Basic.

[Working Directory Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZb7H.png)

Edit. My actual code:

```
Private Function unpinFromTaskbar()
    Dim advancedProcess As New ProcessStartInfo
    advancedProcess.FileName = INSTALL_PATH + "\syspin.exe"
    advancedProcess.Arguments = """C:\Program Files\OEM\BrowserChoice\OEMBrowserChoice.exe"" 5387"
    advancedProcess.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
    Try
        Process.Start(advancedProcess)
        ' Here it's going to be
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' ex is empty
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: The only thing wrong with the code you posted - I don't think it would even cause an issue - is the space at the start of the second string.  That's not required.  Everything else looks correct.  There are two potential issues that I can see that have nothing to do with quoting arguments.  Either `INSTALL_PATH` is incorrect or it's an issue with the working directory.  Maybe tell us what actually happens when you execute that code, as you should have done - everyone should do when posting a question - in the first place.

Comment: I suspect that the issue is going to be the working directory, which will be the same as your app's process by default.  If 'syspin.exe' assumes that its own folder is its working directory then it will fail to find required files.  What you ought to do in that case is create a `ProcessStartInfo` object and pass that to `Process.Start`.  The file name would be `IO.Path.Combine(INSTALL_PATH, "syspin.exe")`, the arguments would be `"""C:\Program Files\OEM\BrowserChoice\OEMBrowserChoice.exe"" 5387"` and the working directory would be `INSTALL_PATH`.

Comment: By the way, you also ought to use `Environment.GetFolderPath` or `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories` to get the Program Files path.  Even if it's for your own use, you may find that you want to use the program one day with a non-standard path.  Never hard-code when there's a simple alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer.
It's nothing happening, it's running through and tell me everything successful executed...
I am detecting the location of the exe using:
Private INSTALL_PATH As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory

Comment: To get the directory from where your executable is run, you can use `Application.StatupPath`, `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`, 
`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`, a few more. `Environment.CurrentDirectory` is not one of those.

Comment: So, are you saying that you have 'syspin.exe' in the same folder as your own executable - the current executable?

Comment: Application.StartupPath did the job, now it's working fine, Thank you

Comment: Yes, they're in the same folder